# When a Row is deleted how Can I delete all associated rows in other tables? LARAVEL 5.4

Tags: laravel

I wrote this function but wondering if there's a "laravel" way to do the same functionality?

I want to delete all the rows in my other tables that are related to the row I'm deleting.

```
    $id = 6;

    $query = "SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME 
              FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
              WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'exercise_id'";

    $tables = DB::select($query);

    foreach ($tables as $table) :

        $rows = DB::table($table->TABLE_NAME)
               ->select($table->COLUMN_NAME)
               ->where($table->COLUMN_NAME, '=', $id)
               ->delete();

    endforeach;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would typically be done with cascading deletes on the foreign keys when modifying the schema.

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#foreign-key-constraints
There, the docs state:

> You may also specify the desired action for the "on delete" and "on
>   update" properties of the constraint:

```
$table->foreign('user_id')
      ->references('id')
      ->on('users')
      ->onDelete('cascade');
```

PS: This approach is not neccesarily limited to laravel (laravel way of doing it)

Answer (score 3):

Add [foreign key constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#foreign-key-constraints) and use `->onDelete('cascade')`:

```
$table->foreign('user_id')
      ->references('id')
      ->on('users')
      ->onDelete('cascade');
```

In this case, all related data in other tables will be deleted automatically.